# How to define foreign Key in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I am trying to achieve the below table structure, but I am getting error
"cannot be used as a property on entity type because it is configured as a navigation."

Can anyone help me.

**Category:**

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cat1 |
| 2 | cat2 |
| 3 | cat3 |
| 4 | cat4 |

**Sub Category:**

| Id | Category Id | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Subcat1 |
| 2 | 1 | Subcat2 |
| 3 | 1 | Subcat3 |
| 1 | 2 | Subcat4 |
| 1 | 3 | Subcat5 |
| 2 | 3 | Subcat6 |

**Item:**

| Id | CategoryId | SubCategoryId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | item1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | item2 |
| 3 | 1 | null | item3 |
| 4 | 4 | null | item4 |

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HrCodeSubType> SubCategories { get; set; }

}

public class SubCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category{ get; set; }


    public int? SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
  }
```

**Fluent Api**

```
builder.Entity<Item>().HasOne(x => x.SubCategory)
         .WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => new { x.CategoyId, x.SubCategoyId });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

leave only subcategory in the item class since it depends on category already and has one to one relation

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    
    public int? SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
  }
```

and if you use net core 5+ you don't need any fluent apis, just add navigaion property to subcategory

```
public class SubCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Item> Items{ get; set; }

}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But there will be items with only category and sub category is empty. Can achieve this, if i remove category and leave only sub category

Comment: @mohammedali You have to keep the same structrure, otherwise you will have big problems sooner or later. Just create a fake subcategory that you can call for example "No subcategory".

Comment: I get the error on update-database after removing Category property from Item  . The property 'Item.SubCategory' is of type 'SubCategory' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

Comment: @mohammedali  after making the changes you will have  to make the init database migration.

Comment: On add-migration it didn't show up any error and the script was generated. The above error was raised on database-update after migration

Comment: @mohammedali Don't use add migration, delete the previous migration folder and db and start from zero.

Comment: thnks a lot. Worked after clearing everything. Can I know how can I achieve the case if item has a category and empty subcategory as subcategory is optional (Without unsing No SubCategory option as you suggested)

Comment: @The only way to do this is to put category and subcategory in the same table and have only one table. You can add flag category or not.  But the code will be much more complicated.  Or another way  is to add a flag to subcategory to mark it as a category. But all of these look very messy for me.

Comment: Than you for quick response